# Meaning of docker image tag: 'onbuild', 'jessie', 'stretch'

Tags: docker, dockerfile

https://hub.docker.com/_/node?tab=tags&page=2

I saw some different suffix follow the tag number, like 'onbuild', 'jessie', 'stretch', who knows the actual meaning？

Comment: This is described on the "Description" tab of that page.

Comment: @DavidMaze just saw the "Description" tab, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`jessie` means Debian 8.

`stretch` means Debian 9.

`onbuild` means its Dockerfile contains the `onbuild` instruction, which will be executed when you use it as a parent image (`FROM`).

Comment: Aha, I found the more detail description on the  "Description" tab, thanks.